# Invoke-Command only works when domain admin is logged in on remote computer

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, terminal-services

We have 7 Terminal Servers, and for some reason, I can only use `Invoke-Command` on those two, when the domain administrator is logged on to the servers.

I will get this error, when I try to use `Invoke-Command` on them, when the domain administrator isn't logged on to them. The other 5 servers have no issue.
As soon as I log in with the remote administrator, it works flawlessly.

```
[RDH004] Connecting to remote server RDH004 failed with the following error message : The WSMan service could not launch a host process to process the given request.  Make s
ure the WSMan provider host server and proxy are properly registered. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (RDH004:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I did doublecheck if the service Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) was running. And I did create a GPO (Allow remote server management through WinRM) to allow remote connections.

Did the same thing, on all servers to attempt to enable it. All servers are a clone from the same template in ESXi. And all servers are running Windows Server 2016.

I've searched far and wide for solutions, but none of the solutions seem to be the same problem. Especially not, since it works if the server I'm trying to send a remote command to, has the domain administrator logged in.

Comment: So lets get this a little clear. Your computer communicates via the WS-Man, or Web Services for Management, protocol. This is an HTTP(s)-based protocol that can encapsulate a variety of different communications. ON the remote computer, the Windows Remote Management (WinRM) service runs, This service is configured to have one or more listeners. Each listener waits for incoming WS-Man traffic on a specific port, each bound to a specific protocol (HTTP or HTTPS), and on Specific IP Address or all Local addresses. Does you account have permissions to the remote PC? Have you ran `Enable-PSRemoting`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes, I did Indeed run `Enable-PSRemoting`. I even added -Force to it aswell. And I did enable the wildcard listening address for both IPv4 and IPv6 - just to be sure.
I think I have attempted every solution, on the first 3 pages of Google, when I search for my error. With and without adding "Powershell" to the search. Also varies combinations of "invoke-command not working", "powershell remote management error", "wsman could not launch" etc.
But for some reason, it will only work, when the domain admin is logged in on those two servers.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue is due to the Windows User Account Control (UAC). The remote account must be a domain account and a member of the remote computer Administrators group. If the account is a local computer member of the Administrators group, then UAC does not allow access to the WinRM service. This error happens even if the account is a Local Administrator and the command line is run with administrator privileges.

To solve the problem, UAC filtering for local accounts must be disabled by creating the following DWORD registry entry and setting its value to 1:

[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy

Additional Information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/obtaining-data-from-a-remote-computer

Comment: I did try this exact solution you're posting. It doesn't resolve my issue.


I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I think you only need this with a computer outside of active directory.